# Can't migrate:fresh -seed errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: laravel

Yet here I am with another errno 150. Tried most of everything around here with no luck now I need a expert who might see the mistake within my code.

When trying to `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

Getting error 1005-150

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `webmall`.`order_items` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `order_items` add constraint `order_items_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references `products` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

order_items migration:

```
Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->float('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Databaseseeder.php

```
public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ProductSeeder::class);
        $this->call(DataTypesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(DataRowsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PostsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PagesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(MenusTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(MenuItemsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserRolesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PermissionRoleTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(SettingsTableSeeder::class);

        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
```

thank you as usuall!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your foreign key has a different type from the primary key it references.

It is very conventional to use bigIncrements as id/primary key column so if you're referencing it you must use bigInteger
So your migration should look like

```
Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
        $table->BigInteger('product_id');

        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('quantity');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Sadly this didn't work. I also have tried some other alternatives seen around like addin unsigned() instead of unsignedBigInteger and so on.